# Fields for nested attributes inside loop in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I tried to do something like google my business where you have the days of the week and you can add multiple times to it. I follow the [rail cast nested model form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), but I have not been able to make it work the way I would like to.

I want to have a location with the 7 days of the week and you can add multiple times to each day. Create method seems to work as expected as the form is there from scratch. Then when I go into edit, each day has all the times that were saved on create.

I would just like some guidance in this issue. Thanks!

_from.html.erb

```
<% (0..6).each do |idx| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><% I18n.t('date.day_names')[idx] %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= form.fields_for :times do |f| %>
        <%= render "time_fields", :form => f %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Time", "btn", "repeater-add",  form, :times %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

_time_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="weekday-time" id="time">
  <%= form.hidden_field :weekday_id, value: form.options[:child_index] %>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
      <%= form.text_field :time, id: "timepicker" %>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= link_to_remove_fields "Delete Time, "btn", "repeater-remove", form %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
  @location.times.build
end
```

Models

```
class Time < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :location, optional: true
end

class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :times, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :times
end
```

**EDIT**

After trying different things I got the result that I wanted. However, not sure if this is the best way to do it.

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, html_class, data_attr, html_id, form)
    form.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, html_class, html_id, data_attr, "remove_fields(this)")
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, html_class, html_id, data_attr, form, association, idx)
    new_object = form.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = form.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :form => builder, idx: idx)
    end
    link_to_function(name, html_class, html_id, data_attr, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end

  def link_to_function(name, html_class, html_id, data_attr, *args, &block)
     html_options = args.extract_options!.symbolize_keys

     function = block_given? ? update_page(&block) : args[0] || ''
     onclick = "#{"#{html_options[:onclick]}; " if html_options[:onclick]}#{function}; return false;"
     href = html_options[:href] || '#'

     content_tag(:a, name, html_options.merge(:href => href, :onclick => onclick, :class => html_class, :id => html_id, :data_attr => data_attr))
  end  
end
```

location_controller.rb

```
def new
  @location = Location.new
end

def edit
  @times = Times.where(location_id: @location.id)
end
```

_time_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="weekday-time" id="time">
  <%= form.hidden_field :weekday_id, value: idx %>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
      <%= form.text_field :time, id: "timepicker" %>
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "Delete Time, "btn", "plahecolder", "repeater-remove", form %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<% (0..6).each do |idx| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><%= I18n.t('date.day_names')[idx] %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div id="time<%= idx %>">
        <% _current_time = @location.new_record? ? @location.times.build : @times.where(location_id: idx) %>
        <% unless _current_time.blank? %>
          <%= form.fields_for :times, _current_time do |f| %>
            <%= render "time_fields", :form => f, :idx => idx %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- add button -->
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Time", "btn", "repeater-add", "time#{idx}",  form, :times, idx %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

js

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("true");
  $(link).closest(".weekday-time").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  let _attr = $(link).attr('data_attr');
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");
  $(content.replace(regexp, new_id)).insertAfter($("#" + _attr));
}
```

Comment: What is your desired result? Are you expecting the times that are already entered to be static/not editable? To be absent from the edit form?

Comment: @ArtemIgnatiev I want to be able to edit and delete the times on edit. The expected result is that on create I can add multiple times and on edit I am still able to change those times, delete them or add new times.

Comment: For me, it is unclear what the result you have obtained so far, and what is missing from it to be what you are trying to achieve. Also it could also be helpful if you share your controller code beyond the `new` action.

Comment: I agree with @ArtemIgnatiev. link_to_add/remove_fields methods would be useful, also your JS code.   As I had some encounters with nested fields, I would recommend you use a dedicated gem ( cocoon would be my 1st solution, nested_form gem 2nd one) .It won't be hard to adapt it to what you already done and it will ease your work a lot.

Comment: @VictorLuna you want all 7 days as a location in one single form or each day as its own separate form e.g. one form submit will post data of all the seven days and timings or one at a time?

Comment: @Daniel I added an update, where I was able to find the solution. Not sure if this is the best way though. I know about the gems, I would just like to try this for educational purposes.

Comment: @KartikeyTanna 7 days in one form and each day has many times. The params should look something like ""times_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"weekday_id"=>"0", "time"=>"11:00 AM", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"11234515621321"=>{"weekday_id"=>"0", "time"=>"02:00 PM", "_destroy"=>"false"}, 
"1"=>{"weekday_id"=>"1", "time"=>"01:00 PM", "_destroy"=>"false"}.....}

Comment: @ArtemIgnatiev the expected result is one table that holds multiple times with the location id and the weekday_id. The form is in the location view where it has 7 days of the week and you can add multiple time to each day. The reason I did not put the controller beyond new, its because the rest of it its irrelevant. It is the usual respond_to location.save and location.update(location_params)

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be another way to do this. If so please do not hesitate to point that out and answer this question. However, if someone is looking for a solution with a similar problem this is what I did.

I iterate through the days of the week and then on `create`, `_current_time` will return `true`, which can be used as the record_object argument for  `fields_for`. It takes a `record_object` but I have none on `create` so the `true` will suffice (not sure 100% why). Then on `update`, I iterate through the times that have a day of the week and skip the creation of fields that have not.

_form.html.erb

```
<% (0..6).each do |idx| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <p><%= I18n.t('date.day_names')[idx] %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div id="time<%= idx %>">
        <% _current_time = @location.new_record? ? @location.times.build : @times.where(location_id: idx) %>
        <% unless _current_time.blank? %>
          <%= form.fields_for :times, _current_time do |f| %>
            <%= render "time_fields", :form => f, :idx => idx %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Time", "btn", "repeater-add", "time#{idx}",  form, :times, idx %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The add button will create a new time in either situation using the appropriate index for the day of the week. In the edit part on this question you can see the full implementation. Only the `_form.html.erb` was causing the issue, so I am posting just this piece as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Providing the basic solution here. You might need to refactor it.

We are creating seven instances of the Location. Each for a weekday. Although I have not added `weekday_id` column in my solution. I believe you can take care of it.

Then under `create` method, we are taking each param and whitelist them using `locations_params` method and then create the record.

`_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_tag locations_path do |main_form| %>
  <% @locations.each do |location| %>
    <%= fields_for 'locations[]', location do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %> <br>
      <%= f.fields_for :timings, f.object.timings.build do |timing_form| %>
        <%= timing_form.label :start_time %>
        <%= timing_form.text_field :start_time, type: "time" %> <br>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

`locations_controller.rb`

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @locations = []
    7.times do
      @locations << Location.new
    end
  end

  def create
    params[:locations].each do |location|
      Location.create!(locations_params(location))
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def locations_params(my_params)
    my_params.permit(:name, :timings_attributes => [:start_time, :id, :_destroy, :locatino_id])
  end
end
```

`location.rb`

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :timings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :timings
end
```

Explanation of creating multiple records can be found [here](http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2015/07/18/create-multiple-objects-from-single-form-in-rails/).

I have not added `link_to_add_fields` option under the form. You can refer to [Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) you mentioned in the question or use something like [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however this is not what I am looking for. I want to create times with days that are associated to one location. I tried the method you suggested by creating 7 times in new action without success. That will create  as I need to add the times to a day. Some days might not have times. In edit part on the question. I was able to find the solution. However, I am not sure this is the right way to do it